# php (laravel) short hand for creating an array with elements has id property

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create an array like this

```
$a = [ 
  ['id' => 1],
  ['id' => 2],
  ['id' => 3],
  ['id' => 4],
   ....
]
```

just like array_fill but with id property for each element

I known I could do it by loop or anonymous function with array_map but I wonder if there is a short hand for this. I'm using php laravel framework. thanks in advance

Comment: Is each element unique i.e; with different properties with ids?

Comment: yes, I want it like an increment array with ['id' => (increment number)]

Answer (score 0):

The following will do the trick:

```
$a = array_map(function($id) { return ['id' => $id];}, range(1,4));
```

**range(1,4)** will return an array of integers from **1** to **4**.
**array_map()** will convert each element of the array you pass using function provided - this one will convert each number from the array into an array, where given number becomes the **id**.

Comment: thanks for your feedback but as I said I do not want to use loop or anonymous function with array_map, it it not short hand right ?

Comment: right, didn't notice you want to avoid anonymous functions as well. I don't think it's possible - you need to tell PHP how to generate elements of the $a array and if each of them is different, you'll need to define a function that creates them

Comment: thanks for your information, I did a lot of searching but.... I'm currently define my own helper function, but I will be happy to hear that if PHP supports it :D